# Using AlertDialog.Builder's setSingleChoiceItems by ID rather than position

Tags: android, listview, dialog, android-alertdialog

I am using an AlertDialog to display a single choice list of items from a database. I use the AlertDialog.Builder to build it, but I'm stumped as to how I should use the setSingleChoiceItems method in this situation.

Specifically, I know which item should be checked when the dialog is first shown, but I know that by ID, not by position. The setSingleChoiceItems method requires the selected item's position, not ID.

I've thought of two different ways to approach this, but neither of them seem "right":

1. Before using the builder, query the database and count rows until I
   find the ID that I want to be selected. Now I know the position.
   This seems bad though, because it requires a second database query.
2. After using the builder, iterate through the list items and find the
   one with the ID I want selected and then select it after the fact.
   This works, but that means I need to put a -1 in the
   setSingleChoiceItems call and then set it later. This feels like a
   hack to me.

So, my question is, is there some other better method that I'm missing? Or is either of the above the best way to approach this?

Comment: seeing some code would help. Atleast the method where you query and fetch the items

Answer (score 0):

If your ID is also an integer, you can set the position itself as the ID.

Comment: Well, the situation is that I have a database table filled with a list of possible items, and I save off the ID of the selected item. The user can also add and remove items from the database, so there is no guarantee of ID matching position in any way.